# Schrodinger equation for free EM field

Tags: electromagnetism, schroedinger-equation, quantum-electrodynamics

The question come from the fact that I've seen for the first time in my life the quantization of a field, in particular of the free em field. 
I've study how it is possible to write the energy of the em field as a function of canonical coordinates $p_\lambda$ and $q_\lambda$ and how to substitute them with operators $\hat Q_\lambda$ and$\hat P_\lambda$ that obey appropriate commutation rules. Than with some substitution I've studied how to introduce the operators $\hat b$ and $\hat b^\dagger$. With some other substitution I found the operators corresponding to the classical quantity  $\vec A$, $\vec B$, $\vec E$ and so on.

Now the problem is that I feel like I have all the operators of the em field and the commutation rules for them, but i don't know what Is the equation that the wave function of this operators should follow, so I feel like everything I derived is useless.

Is maybe the Schrodinger equation valid for free EM field? Let's say that  $|\Psi\rangle $ is the state of the free EM field and that $\hat H$ is its hamiltonian operator, it it true that $i\hbar\,\partial_t |\Psi\rangle = \hat{H}|\Psi\rangle $?
If not what is the right equation for the wave function of this operators?

Comment: There is a Schrodinger representation of the free photon field (with wave *functionals* instead of wave functions). Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: I've edited the post, I think now it's clearer, thanks

Comment: SimoBartz, thanks for the edit. I think it might take me some time to untangle this. You mention that you're looking for "the wave function for this operators". Do you mean instead the *wave equation* (or equation of motion) for the operators? Also (**and this is important**), if the operators are time dependent, then we're in the *Heisenberg* picture (state fixed in time, operators evolve in time), not the *Schrodinger* picture (state evolves in time, operators fixed in time). So, honestly, it's still not clear to me what you have in mind.

Comment: That's the first time I see field quantization so it's possible that I'm wrong about the concept... I'm in the habit that if I have operators for the observables than I have wave functions on which the operators can be applied. And the wave function should respect the Schrodinger equation. How do I have the same for quantization of a  field? If the concept itself is wrong I'd like to be corrected

Comment: SimoBartz, the 1st chapter of [Mark Srednicki's QFT book](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html) might be a good thing for you to read at this moment. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes your hunch (the last paragraph) is correct. Why should it be otherwise? With all your transformation effectively you 1) made up a quantum version of the Hamiltonian of a free EM field (aka energy) and 2) you also "diagonalized" said quantum Hamiltonian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that equation is correct. The form of the Hamiltonian is

$$
H = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} |p| \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{2} a_i^{\dagger}(p) a_i(p),
$$

with $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ annihilation and creation operators for photons with polarization $i$ respectively.

In fact, the equation that you're written down (usually referred to as the generalized Schrodinger equation, though annav@ seems to disagree) is very general. It is valid for any system which is symmetric under translations in time.

Due to Wigner, in Quantum Mechanics, symmetries can always be represented by either a unitary linear operator, or by an antiunitary antilinear map. Since time translations are a strongly continuous 1-parametric group, they can only be represented by a unitary 1-parametric group acting on the Hilbert space. By [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups), any such group is generated by a self-adjoint operator $H$, which is your Hamiltonian.

Note that similar correspondence holds in the classical theory: invariance under time translations leads to energy conservation (by [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)). The energy observable is nothing other than the classical Hamiltonian.

This equation
$$
i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} \left| \psi \right> = H \left| \psi \right>
$$
is an expression of the invariance of the theory under time translations. Any theory with time translation symmetry obeys an equation like that. It is valid for a non-relativistic particle, for the relativistic particle, for the relativistic field, etc.

In fact, it is only for General Relativistic systems it seems to not hold. In General Relativity, time is described dynamically rather than being a static background. Time translations become a redundancy rather than a genuine symmetry, and an equation like that doesn't exist.

Comment: The S equation is non relativistic ,

Comment: @annav that is a common misconception. The Schrödinger equation for a nonrelativistic particle Hamiltonian $p^2/(2m)$ is indeed non relativistic, but its version with a relativistic Hamiltonian (or in this case relativistic field theory Hamiltonian) is perfectly valid for describing the evolution of a quantum relativistic system.

Comment: they are the Klein Gordon equations and Dirac equations afaik, no longer called Schrodinger https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Relativistic_quantum_mechanics

Comment: @annav it is pretty common (at least among theoreticians) to refer to the equation $i \hbar \frac{d}{dt} \left| \psi \right> = H \left| \psi \right>$ as the generalized Schrodinger equation. Field equations like Klein-Gordon, Dirac, Maxwell (here), etc. are special cases for different choices of $H$.

Comment: @annav I don't want to argue about terminology, it is possible that different groups are used to different terminology. Leaving aside the issue whether the equation from OP's question should be called Schrodinger or not, it holds in the quantum field theory of free photons, with the Hailtonian given by the formula from my answer.

Comment: i edited the question, now its maybe clearer

Comment: @SimoBartz you are still asking whether that equation describes the time evolution of the quantum field. My answer is still “yes”.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov  I am not saying what you wrote is not correct, but is is not usually called the S equations any longer.if it is relatvistic and it has to be for particle  QFT

Comment: @annav wikipedia seems to disagree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Quantum_field_theory

Comment: What worries me about this answer is this: when I see the generalized (or abstract) Schrodinger equation in your answer, I see *state vectors*. At the Wikipedia article section linked in the comment above, it is stated that: *The general equation is also valid and used in quantum field theory, both in relativistic and nonrelativistic situations. However, the solution ψ is no longer interpreted as a "wave", but should be interpreted as an operator acting on states existing in a Fock space.[citation needed]* - so, if I read this correctly, the $|\psi\rangle$ isn't a ket but rather, an operator?

Comment: (cont.) But, if true, that seems to me to be an almost criminal abuse of notation and of the term "Schrodinger equation".

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Nah, $| \psi >$ is a vector. You’re confusing the two things commonly denoted by the letter $\psi$. The classical field (lets denote it by $\phi$ to avoid confusion) becomes an operator that acts on there vectors, or rather an operator-valued distribution. There exists an expression that relates that operator to creation and annihilation operators acting on the Fock space.

Comment: I don't think I'm confused, and I've think you've missed my point entirely.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri ah oh sorry indeed I have. Yeah, that sentence from Wikipedia is very confusing indeed.

Comment: Yes Legolasov is correct. If there is a Hamiltonian it has to act on vectors ("ket"). The problem is that the Hilbert space of a field theory is not separable and we often avoid dealing with vectors (rather we usually focus on correlation functions (see Wightman functions and so on), which are well defined). But conceptually a field theory is just a system with many particles.

Comment: @lcv your last point is not exactly correct though. The Hilbert space of the field theory *is* separable, if the Field theory is properly defined. Wightman shows that to a collection of Wightman functions satisfying the axioms, we can always associate a separable Hilbert space. That space is not Fock when the theory is interacting

Comment: Let me try a different approach. Write the SE in the coordinate representation where $\psi(x,t)$ is a wavefunction (coordinate rep of the time dependent state vector $|\psi(t)\rangle$). Reinterpret the TDSE as an operator equation of motion for the (operator valued) field $\psi(x,t)$. Though they look similar, the former equation is a coordinate representation of the generalized SE while the later isn't. Indeed, we've left the Schrodinger picture where the state vector carries the time dependence.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov correct. But that's precisely a way to try to reconstruct a "decent" Hilbert space from Wightman functions. The naive Hilbert space that you get by doing the thermodynamic limit is not separable. Anyway all this discussion is not to the point of the question :) I agree with your answer

Comment: By the way +1. And some more useless characters.

Answer (score 4):

The Schroedinger  equation is nothing but the statement of the Stone theorem when the one-parameter group is the time evolution. It does not matter if the system is relativistic or classic, it only matters that you know the Hamiltonian $H$ of the system. The equation has always the form
$$\frac{d}{dt} \psi = -iH \psi .$$
For free quantum field theories the Schroedinger equation can be stated both for a pure state of one particle or for a pure state of many particles. It is false that equations as Klein Gordon and Dirac are the Schroedinger equations because they are not a statement of Stone's theorem. To obtain that statement you usually have to transform  these equations. For instance to produce the Schroedinger equation of a KG particle we have to correctly recognize its Hamiltonian and its Hilbert space (made of only positive frequency solutions of the KG equation). This procedure produces a Hamiltonian operator which is non-local and it is represented by a pseudo-differential operator 
$$H = \sqrt{-\Delta +m^2}.$$
The field equations as KG or Dirac, in this context of Schroedinger picture for states and in counterposition to the Heisenberg picture for operators, are more complicated equations which permit to write the evolution into an apparently local form. E.g. the KG equation can be written
$$(\frac{d}{dt} -iH)(\frac{d}{dt} + iH)\psi =0\:.$$

Comment: That’s basically my answer, copy-pasted...

Comment: Ah Sorry, I did not see you answer, I am using my phone and it is a bit difficult to see everything. I answered without reading the other answers. Let me have a look at them.

Comment: Yes there is a big overlap.

Comment: I do not know if it is politically correct to remove my answer even if there is such an overlap, since I did not see it. The fact that we say the same things only means that we have the same (correct) view on this issue.

Comment: no need, all good

Comment: I think this goes more towards what I think lies at the root of OP's question. OP seems to wonder (in a comment) where the wavefunction is that all these field operators act on,   and if that wavefunction obeys a Schrodinger equation.

Answer (score 0):

> That's the first time I see field quantization so it's possible that
>   I'm wrong about the concept... I'm in the habit that if I have
>   operators for the observables than I have wave functions on which the
>   operators can be applied. And the wave function should respect the
>   Schrodinger equation.

I'll make an attempt to untangle this a bit.

First, it's true that in the *Schrodinger picture* of quantum mechanics, the state vector $|\psi(t)\rangle$ of the system is time dependent and obeys the abstract Schrodinger equation:

$$H|\psi(t)\rangle = i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle $$

On the (one-particle) coordinate basis $|\mathbf{x}\rangle$, the state vectors are wave functions, and the Hamiltonian is a differential operator:

$$\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf{x})\right)\psi(\mathbf{x},t) = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$$

There is another picture, the *Heisenberg* picture where the state vector of the system is *not* time dependent; in this picture the *operators* are time dependent.

Now, in the Heisenberg picture, instead of Schrodinger equation that governs the time evolution of the state vector, there is an operator equation of motion (since the operators carry the time dependence rather than the state vectors).

However, there *is* a (time independent) state vector $|\psi_H\rangle$ (the subscript H indicates the Heisenberg picture) that satisfies

$$|\psi_H\rangle = |\psi(0))\rangle$$

That is, the state vectors in the Heisenberg and Schrodinger pictures are equal at time $t=0$.

Finally, for the dynamics, the Heisenberg equation of motion for operators is*

$$\frac{d}{dt}A(t)=\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,A(t)]$$

---

With that out of the way, a point that (to me) is too quickly passed over in many introductions to quantum fields is that in passing from a wave equation for a wave function (Schrodinger picture) to a wave equation for a quantum field, we change pictures to the Heisenberg picture (where the operators are time dependent).

That is, the equation of motion that the (operator valued) free photon field must satisfy is not due to a Schrodinger's equation (which, again, governs the time evolution of *state vectors*).

That isn't to say that there isn't a Schrodinger picture (representation) of the free photon field with time dependent wavefunction(al)s that obey a Schrodinger's equation. I'll quote from chapter 10 (Free Fields in the Schrodinger Representation) of Brian Hatfield's *Quantum Field Theory of Point Particles and Strings*:

> For field theory in the Schrodinger representation, we must only
>   substitute the word "functional" for "function". Differential
>   representations of the canonical commutators are obtained by replacing
>   conjugate momenta with functional derivatives. Coordinate
>   representations of state vectors or elements of Fock space are wave
>   functionals. The Schrodinger equation is a functional differential
>   equation whose solutions, the eigenfunctionals of the Hamiltonian
>   functional differential operator, **represent possible states of the
>   system.**

(emphasis mine)

---

Looking around here for some relevant Q & A (or for anything that might be helpful - I'll update from time to time):

[Field operator in Schrodinger Picture](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/56777/9887)

[State, Dynamics and Interpretation in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/419581/9887)

[Schrodinger functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_functional)

Comment: I don’t understand this answer. The Schrödinger equation does not need wavefunctionals — you can define it on the Fock space in a free QFT, which is a mathematically well defined separable Hilbert space

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov, that's interesting. Here's a quote from Hatfield's text:  *For field theory in the Schrodinger representation, we must only substitute the word "functional" for "function" ... Coordinate representations of state vectors or elements of Fock space are wave functionals. The Schrodinger equation is a functional differential equation whose solutions, the eigenfunctionals of the Hamiltonian functional differential operator, represent possible states of the system.* - Is Hatfield incorrect?

Comment: that quote doesn’t contradict what I wrote. Fock space elements can be written as certain wavefunctionals (though not all wavefunctionals are elements of the Fock space). However, to work directly with all wavefunctionals is not mathematically possible, because they form a nonsearable space. Whereas you can work with the separable and well-defined Fock space without ever referring to wavefunctionals, at least in non-interacting QFT. Reference: any introductory level QFT textbook.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov, to be sure I understand your objection, are you saying that the coordinate representation of the Schrodinger equation (in non-interacting QFT) does not require wavefunctionals?

Comment: I’m saying that coordinate representation simply doesn’t exist, mathematically. You may be able to write it down formally to capture intuition, but it won’t be an equation on operators acting on a Hilbert space. Unless you restrict it to the Fock space, but that is not a coordinate representation.

Comment: Alfred Centuari, your answer was illuminating but maybe not perfectly fit to my question, I've done a similar question that is maybe more fitted to your answer, if you like to look at it :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/556823/quantization-of-free-em-field-doubt-about-the-field-operators

Comment: @SimoBartz, thank you for the feedback.