# Quantization of free EM field, doubt about the field operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform

this is the first time that I study fields quantization and in particular I'm starting with the free em field. Previously I've just studied the non relativistic, Schrodinger equation for a non zero mass particle (in the Schrodinger picture), so I'm trying to use the same ideas to understand this topic. If you feel like I'm missing the concepts and my question is nonsense I'd like to corrected and change my current understanding.

My questions arise from the quantization process of the potential vector $\vec A$ that I've study: using Fourier and doing some math it is possible to write down:
$$\vec A(\vec x,t)=\sum_\lambda \vec a_\lambda(t) e^{i \vec k \cdot \vec x}+\vec a_\lambda^*(t) e^{-i \vec k \cdot \vec x}$$
Thus substituting the "generalized coordinates" $\vec a_\lambda(t)$ with the respective operator $\hat a_\lambda$ it results:

$$\hat {\vec A}(\vec x)=\sum_\lambda \vec \pi_\lambda(\hat a_\lambda e^{i \vec k \cdot \vec x}+\hat a_\lambda^\dagger e^{-i \vec k \cdot \vec x})$$

where $\vec \pi_\lambda$ is the polarization unit vector.

The question are:

1. In the quantization process I don't see that we introduce a basis for the operators, but in the resulting operator it appears $\vec x$ instead of $\hat {\vec x}$, does it mean that somehow we've chosen the position basis, or maybe should i interpret the operator field differently form any operators that we see in the one particle quantum mechanics?
2. The time dependence is disappeared, is it because this is the Schrodinger picture?

Comment: To clarify: (1) Is the subscript $\lambda$ related to $\vec k$?  If not, the $a$'s should depend on $\vec k$. That's important because it relates to your first question. (2) To explain why the time-dependence disappeared, more context is needed. Probably they just switched to the Schrödinger picture, and they should have said that explicitly (because it's *not* required as part of the quantization process). What reference are you using?

Comment: $\lambda=\vec k, j$ where j is one of the two component of the polarization vector

Comment: *"but in the resulting operator it appears $\vec{x}$ instead of $\hat{\vec{x}}$, does it mean that somehow we've chosen the position basis"* - SimoBartz, does it help if I point out that, for relativistic covariance, position and time need be treated the same? Since $t$ is a parameter (label) in QM, the QFT approach is to 'demote' position from an *observable* to a label. That is, $\vec{x}$ is no longer an eigenvalue of an operator.